# Is it possible to set ARGB background color to IText PDF cell?

Tags: java, itext, awt

In iText PDF we can set background color to a cell like this

```
PdfPCell cell = buildCell(phrase, displayType, col);
cell.setBackgroundColor(new java.awt.Color(33, 150, 243, 153));
```

But it turns out that iText ignores the `java.awt.Color` opacity.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Support for transparent background colors has been added in iText 5.5.7, more exactly in commit 09ccaa728830a404e92fc3040dd3626198576fef. You appear to use an older iText version, though, as indicated by your use of a `java.awt.Color` instead of a `com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor`.

Comment: I saw some examples using BaseColor, and had some thoughts about wrong version as I couldn't find the class in my libs. Your comment made things clear, thank you.

Comment: Shall I make the comment an answer? Or do you want to wait for some solution making use of events or some other mechanism to induce transparency support?

Comment: I guess that's a good answer for my question. I can search for workarounds elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for transparent cell background colors has been added in iText 5.5.7, more exactly in git commit 09ccaa728830a404e92fc3040dd3626198576fef.

You appear to use an older iText version, though, as indicated by your use of a `java.awt.Color` instead of a `com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor`.

Depending on the exact version of iText you may try and use a `PdfPCellEvent` implementation instead of setting the background color with `setBackgroundColor`. In that implementation you'd have to first save the graphics state, then set a `PdfGState` with transparency, fill the cell rectangle with the color, and restore the graphics state again.